# Want to build my own WiFi antenna, don't know what connector I need

Tags: usb, connector, wireless-networking

I have a TP-LINK TLGWN722N WiFi USB adapter. The adapter has a connector on it so you can attach different external antennas to it. The manufacturer's website states the connector is RP-SMA. However, I think the connector is very small; it's 3/16 inches in diameter. I would assume the connector is female since it's reverse polarity and has a pin in the middle of the connector.

Would just buying a cable that's RP-SMA male allow me to connect to it?

Every coax cable I've found in my attic seems to be twice the diameter of the connector on the WiFi USB. I have a RG58 cable and the connectors on either end are twice the size of the connector on the USB. I thought that RG58 was made for RF (WiFi) purposes. I'd appreciate any insight on this.

The connector in question:
[image]

Comment: If you google "RP-SMA" and actually check the size you get the answer. "don't know what connector I need", you even tell us that you do - the manufacturer told you.

Comment: The last time I handled RG58 was in an old 10Mbps coax Ethernet installation and it had BNC (push & 90deg twist) connectors. I very much doubt RG58 is at all suitable for WiFi.

Comment: Depending on your jurisdiction, building your own antenna could be illegal. For instance, in the U.S. you would need to subject it to FCC approval.

Comment: pipe, I've tried googling and found this link: http://blog.showmecables.com/sma-dimensions/; I wanted to make sure that my connector on my WiFi USB is RP-SMA female, and the connector I need on the coax is RP-SMA male. Ron Maupin, I've already looked at the FCC guidelines and I'm under the EIRP maximum for the 2.4GHz band (52dBM).

Comment: @brhans you'd be surprised what you can get down a good length of RG58.... Excetna, any chance of a picture of the connector in question? for example an RP-SMA looks something like http://www.gigatronix.co.uk/default.php?_minc=show_part_template_1&_lang=&gpdb_product_id=5817& and is less common.  A standard SMA jack is more the norm: http://www.gigatronix.co.uk/default.php?_minc=show_part_template_1&_lang=&gpdb_product_id=3425&

Comment: Basically is the centre contact on the side you have a socket or pin?

Comment: Mokubai, here's a picture of it: http://imgur.com/4wyxm5H I just think the connector on the WiFi USB is smaller than normal. I've heard that manufacturers use propreitary connectors so that it's more difficult to plug in a non-standard antenna. I don't know whether or not that's true thought.

Comment: @Excetna While I admit it's possible for them to make their own connector I would expect those manufacturers to be either the really big ones who can afford it, or for that company to be in the minority of companies that don't actually want to sell anything.  While there are a *lot* of RF connectors manufacturers generally do stick to the standard set.

Answer (score 0):

The connector you have is, as you have stated, definitely looks to me like an [RP-SMA **Jack**](http://www.gigatronix.co.uk/default.php?_minc=show_part_template_1&_lang=&gpdb_product_id=3462&). In order to connect to it you need an RP-SMA Plug such as [this one](http://www.gigatronix.co.uk/default.php?_minc=show_part_template_1&_lang=&gpdb_product_id=4037&).  There aren't many threaded RF connectors down at that size and SMA is quite distinctive.

3/16 of an inch is approximately the right diameter, once you take account of measurement error, of an external SMA connector which [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMA_connector) states `employs a 1/4 inch, 36 thread`

For the record, with SMA the "plug" and "jack" designations refer to the outer shield of the connector while "RP" and normal refer to which way round the pin and socket centre connector are.  Normal is for the pin to be on the side with the rotating (internally threaded) side (plug) while the reversed would have the pin contact on the externally threaded side (jack).

These contrived naming conventions are why people hate connectors.

So yes, an RG58 RP-SMA Plug would suffice for what you are trying to do, though smaller diameter cable and SMA connectors do exist.  Generally though the smaller diameter cables have a greater signal loss. See this [handy cable selection guide](http://www.l-com.com/multimedia/catalog_page/2K8M1_060%20Selecting%20the%20Right%20Cable.pdf)

Comment: @Mokubail, I'll order a RP-SMA plug and let you know how it goes. Thanks for your help.